# Pushing a specific ancestral commit with Gerrit and git-review

Tags: git, gerrit, git-review

Say I have a Git history that looks like this, for newest to oldest:

```
* C: WIP: Latest change
* B: WIP: Older changer
* A: Groundwork/housekeeping - review ready
* (origin/master) Existing master commit
* ...
```

Commits B and C are work in progress, and I'm not ready to send for review yet, but I have some housekeeping/groundwork that I have split out into commit A and rebased in front of B and C. I am ready to send this for review.

I know I can create a new branch at commit A and review that, or reset/checkout, review and return, but is there a simple one liner with `git-review` that I can use to send just this one commit for review?

Comment: I would like to suggest local branch as much as you can, so that you can avoid such cases.

Comment: @love, sure, I know how to do that (this is all on a topic branch anyway), just lazily trying to save branching, rebasing or checking out when the code to be reviewed is a simple ancestor.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new branch using `git branch` for whatever target commit you want. In your case, if you want to create a new branch pointing at `A`, you can do it like this:

```
git branch newbranch A
```

You can also use the `checkout -b` syntax to check it out immediately:

```
git checkout -b newbranch A
```

You can then submit that branch and its commit A for review. Once it’s merged in, you can rebase `B` and `C` so they base off the new `origin/master`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible with git-review, but you can do this without git-review using raw push command.

For example usually without git-review you will use command like this:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

And if you want to push only one (it will be one only in case if all commits before `A` are already in `master`) specific commit, for example commit `A`, you can use its hash instead of `HEAD`:

```
git push origin A:refs/for/master
```

---

But usage of hash is not very nice because you should know it and you can do this in more easier way using construction like this `HEAD~2`, this will tell git use third commit starting from `HEAD` and in your case it will be `A`:

```
git push origin HEAD~2:refs/for/master
```

---

But construction like `git push origin HEAD~2:refs/for/master` is too long and instead of it you can create several [git aliases](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) like this (example aliases bellow will always use `master` as destination branch, so if in your workflow you are using several destination branches like `master` with `development` then you will need to create aliases for each branch like `review-master-2` and `review-development-2`):

```
git config --global alias.review-1 'push origin HEAD~1:refs/for/master'
git config --global alias.review-2 'push origin HEAD~2:refs/for/master'
git config --global alias.review-3 'push origin HEAD~3:refs/for/master'
git config --global alias.review-4 'push origin HEAD~4:refs/for/master'
git config --global alias.review-5 'push origin HEAD~5:refs/for/master'
```

And with aliases you can push commit `A` using short command like this:

```
git review-2
```